# Chrome not caching large JS file sent from Express

Tags: node.js, express, swagger, openapi

I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ui-express and my code is basically the first example.

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express');
const swaggerDocument = require('./swagger.json');


app.use('/', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocument));

app.listen(3000)
```

sample `swagger.json` file https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json

[image]
`swagger-ui-express` send a 1 MB `swagger-ui-bundle.js` file that's basically a library that generates the page, this takes a long time to load. I want Chrome to cache that file but every time I refresh it loads it again. How do I force Chrome to cache this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot I had "disable cache" enabled in the network tab... I'm sorry.